# Require help with upserting data extension using PrimaryKey - duplicate key

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am unable to upsert data extension.

I have followed the [adding data to data extension object](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_data_to_data_extension_object/) example and request returns error of `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint` ... `Cannot insert duplicate key in object`.

Data extension has account_id set to primary key.

Following is sample of CREATE request.

```
<soap:Body>
  <CreateRequest 
    xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options>
      <SaveOptions/>
    </Options>
    <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
      <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
      <CustomerKey>Definition_Key</CustomerKey>
      <Properties>
        <Property>
          <Name>name</Name>
          <Value>Sam Sample</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>email</Name>
          <Value>sample@example.com</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>account_id</Name>
          <Value>12345678</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>PrimaryKey</Name>
          <Value>account_id</Value>
        </Property>
      </Properties>
    </Objects>
  </CreateRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a SaveAction of `UpdateAdd` in your <strike>CreateRequest</strike> `UpdateRequest` SaveOptions.

EDIT: (removed bad example)

EDIT: Here's one I captured from a successful operation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Update</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7399de64-edd5-4b99-bd43-ef7373c0fd16</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-05-08T13:02:09.665Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-05-08T13:07:09.665Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-152faf22-08bb-49c1-a90c-97ef9a2cf763-1">
            <o:Username>
               <!-- Removed-->
            </o:Username>
            <o:Password>
               <!-- Removed-->
            </o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
            <SaveOptions>
               <SaveOption>
                  <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                  <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
               </SaveOption>
            </SaveOptions>
         </Options>
         <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <CustomerKey>DATA_EXTENSION_CUSTOMER_KEY</CustomerKey>
            <Properties>
               <Property>
                  <Name>email</Name>
                  <Value>aspriggs@degdigital.com</Value>
               </Property>
               <Property>
                  <Name>firstname</Name>
                  <Value>Adam</Value>
               </Property>
               <Property>
                  <Name>zipcode</Name>
                  <Value>55555</Value>
               </Property>
            </Properties>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to resolve.

Response after adding `UpdateAdd` 

     <CreateResponse 
      xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionCreateResult">
        <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
        <StatusMessage>SaveAction: UpdateAdd violation</StatusMessage>
        <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
        <ErrorCode>68001</ErrorCode>
        <NewID>0</NewID>
        <ErrorMessage>SaveAction: UpdateAdd violation</ErrorMessage>
      </Results>
      <RequestID>123</RequestID>
      <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
     </CreateResponse>

Comment: what are the names and data types of your target data extension?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I changed request to `Update` and works as expected - thanks for your help.